# React - What can cause white flash of the screen after server render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering

In React JS, in development, I have server rendering working. Also, I made sure to have same checksum between server render and client render. The client render is identical to the server render, however during the switch between the two there is a white flash on the screen. What could cause that?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, there is a white flash when react is removing the entire DOM created by prerender to replace with it's own.

Comment: ì changed my configuration and this problem was solved. But not sure exactly what solved it.

Comment: Which configuration exactly?

Comment: The problem likely comes from your "client.js" file where something is causing an unnecessary rerender. I copied the configuration from this starter kit and now it works fine : https://github.com/DominicTobias/universal-react

Answer (score 0):

Search for FOUC (Flash OF Unstyled Content).

Also, check answers here:

[How to stop FOUC when using css loaded by webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36453826/how-to-stop-fouc-when-using-css-loaded-by-webpack)