# FOUC only if webpack Bootstrap bundle included at end of <body>

Tags: webpack, bootstrap-4

I’m just learning webpack. As an exercise, I’ve used it to bundle Bootstrap. If I use the bundle with one of their basic examples, the [Starter Template](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/starter-template/), I get a FOUC if I put `<script src="./main.js"></script>` at the end of the `<body>`. There’s no FOUC if I put it at the beginning of the `<body>`.

Should the `<script>` go at the beginning of the `<body>`? Or should it go at the end of the `<body>`, in which case some other method should be used to prevent the FOUC? For example, use [mini-css-extract-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin) to create a separate CSS file rather than include it in the webpack JS bundle as described in other posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36453826/how-to-stop-fouc-when-using-css-loaded-by-webpack).

#### Code

**dist/index.html**

Same as [Starter Template | Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/starter-template/) except

- Remove the stylesheet `<link>` and JS `<script>` lines
- Insert `<script src="./main.js"></script>`

  - At beggining of `<body>`: no FOUC
  - At end of `<body>`: FOUC

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(scss)$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'style-loader', // inject CSS to page
                }, {
                    loader: 'css-loader', // translates CSS into CommonJS modules
                }, {
                    loader: 'postcss-loader', // Run postcss actions
                    options: {
                        plugins: function () { // postcss plugins, can be exported to postcss.config.js
                            return [
                                require('autoprefixer')
                            ];
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    loader: 'sass-loader' // compiles Sass to CSS
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

**src/index.js**

```js
import 'bootstrap';
import './scss/index.scss';
```

**src/scss/index.scss**

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "custom";
```

Where `scss/_custom.scss` is trivial.

**Environment**: webpack: 4.44, bootstrap: 4.4, Chrome: v80, Firefox: v78, Edge: v44 (these browsers all had a FOUC/no-FOUC as described above).

Answer (score 1):

I'll attempt to answer my own question. Because we don't want content to be
delayed by scripts, in production `<script src="./main.js">` should be inserted at the *end* of `<body>`. Also, to prevent a FOUC, in production the CSS should be extracted to
`main.css` using [mini-css-extract-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin) rather than be loaded dynamically from `main.js`.

In development, you may want to use `style-loader` instead of `mini-css-extract-plugin`. This loads CSS dynamically from `main.js` rather than create `main.css`. This allows you do things like [hot module replacement](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/). As mentioned in the [mini-css-extract-plugin repository (https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin):

> [`mini-css-extract-plugin`] should be used only on production builds without
> style-loader in the loaders chain, especially if you want to have HMR in
> development.

The problem is that loading CSS dynamically causes a FOUC unless `main.js` is
loaded at the *beginning* of `<body>`. If this doesn't bother you, then you can leave it at the end. I posted [this example](https://bitbucket.org/ssaccone/webpack-bootstrap-conditional) on Bitbucket that shows how the Bootstrap [starter-template example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/starter-template/) can be compiled from source where `main.js` is automatically inserted at the beginning or end of `<body>` in development and production modes, respectively.

Comment: I've encountered the same problem, and also discovered that the FOUC only occurs when doing a dev build. Production builds, which use `mini-css-extract-plugin`, have no FOUC and feel great.